# Management click on the checkbox: why does not it work?

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

I have a really serious problem that is driving me crazy literally. I have a Dialog with in a SeekBar to manage the brightness manual and a CheckBox to the management of the auto brightness. The problem is in the use of checkboxe. When you open the Dialog if the auto brightness is enabled the checkbox must be, of course, checked, otherwise it should not be. Clearly when you click on the checkbox if auto brightness is enabled must deactivate it and conversely if it is disabled must be enabled. This is the whole class.

When I open the dialog it correctly detects whether the automatic brightness is enabled or not, so correctly puts the flag on the checkbox. What does not work is to disable / enable the auto brightness clicking on the checkbox. I really can not understand why, I have tried everything, you have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: When you're working with `CheckBoxes`, you have to use [OnCheckedChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html). Only with that listener it'll work properly.

Comment: Create a class that extends the OnCheckedChangedListener class. Make a constructor for that class which passes as an argument the brightbar. In the onCheckedChanged method you then include the code for the tick of the checkbox.

Comment: @Geralt I tried as you say it does not work the same.